# OIDC reverse proxy sidecar in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, lua-resty-openidc

I'm trying to secure java applications on kubernetes.

For a simple Springboot app with permitAll, I choose openresty (nginx) with lua-resty-openidc as reverse proxy.

One example that illustrates mostly what I'm trying to do : https://medium.com/@lukas.eichler/securing-pods-with-sidecar-proxies-d84f8d34be3e

It "works" in localhost, but not on kubernetes.

Here's my nginx.conf :

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    lua_package_path '~/lua/?.lua;;';

    resolver ${dns.ip};

    lua_ssl_trusted_certificate /ssl/certs/chain.pem;
    lua_ssl_verify_depth 5;

    lua_shared_dict discovery 1m;
    lua_shared_dict jwks 1m;
    lua_shared_dict introspection 10m;

    lua_shared_dict sessions 10m;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        server_name  localhost;
        listen       80;

        location /OAuth2Client {
            access_by_lua_block {
                local opts = {
                    discovery = "${openam-provider}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/OAuth2Client/authorization-code/callback",
                    client_id = "myClientId",
                    client_secret = "myClientSecret",
                    scope = "openid profile email",
                }

                local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)

                if err then
                    ngx.status = 500
                    ngx.say(err)
                    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                end

                ngx.req.set_header("Authorization", "Bearer " .. res.access_token)
                ngx.req.set_header("X-USER", res.id_token.sub)
            }

            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/OAuth2Client;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

So in local, as my nginx and my springboot app are running on localhost, the redirections are working.

Now, when I deploy it on kubernetes with this, the browser doesn't map localhost with the internal container ip.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oauth2-client-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: OAuth2Client
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: OAuth2Client
    spec:
      #hostAliases:
      #- ip: "127.0.0.1"
      #  hostnames:
      #  - "oauth2-client.local"
      containers:
      - name: oauth2-client-container
        image: repo/oauth2-client-springboot:latest
        env:
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
            value: dev
        envFrom:
          - secretRef: 
              name: openam-client-secret
          - secretRef: 
              name: keystore-java-opts
        volumeMounts:
          - name: oauth2-client-keystore
            mountPath: "/projected"
            readOnly: true
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
      - name: oauth2-sidecar
        image: repo/oauth2-sidecar:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: oauth2-client-keystore
          projected:
            sources:
              - secret:
                   name: keystore-secret
                   items:
                    - key: keystore.jks
                      path: keystore.jks
              - secret:
                   name: truststore-secret
                   items:
                    - key: truststore.jks
                      path: truststore.jks
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: oauth2-client-service-sidecar
spec:
  selector:
    app: OAuth2Client
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

So how could I map this localhost ? I don't want the app container to be exposed as there's no security on it, that's why I used the nginx as sidecar and the service only targets it. How to tell nginx to redirect_uri and proxypass to the app container ip ?

And subsidiary question : as nginx doesn't accept env variables, how should I do to make it generic, so apps could provide their own redirect_uri that should be used in nginx.conf ?

Another subsidiary question : the command ngx.req.set_header("Authorization", "Bearer " .. res.access_token) doesn't seem to work, as I don't see any Authorization header in my request in my app...

Comment: You could use a service instead a container ip, in this way you don't need to take care of change ip's if your container died. Did you try it?

Comment: But if I use a service for the app container, it'll be reachable from the outside directly, and there's no security on it...

Comment: You could use a service type ClusterIP which is only accessible internally. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) all types of service.

Comment: I just tried. Indeed you're right for the clusterIP, it stays inside. But the prob is, the authZ code grant flow redirects the browser on the clusterIP (which is not reachable) before the proxy_pass. I must be missing something, or maybe it's not possible that way... :s

Comment: Ah in fact, the clusterIP is a really good idea ! Now I changed the redirect_uri to a relative path, and added a new location to that path, and I'm going further ! But now next error, thanks a lot for the suggestion ! :)

Comment: Great! I've posted an answer with this suggestion, please consider accept and up-vote if it was useful, to help the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your service with type `ClusterIP` to be reachable ***only*** internally, then use the fqdn in your services to reach the service without IP dependency.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: oauth2-client-service-sidecar
spec:
  selector:
    app: OAuth2Client
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
```

Then use `oauth2-client-service-sidecar.<namespacen>.cluster.local` in your nginx configuration to reach the service:

```
proxy_pass  http://oauth2-client-service-sidecar.<namespacen>.cluster.local/OAuth2Client;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. But finally I removed the sidecar, to let my nginx as ingress controller, so I just added an ingress in front of my clusterIP, and it works.

Comment: Great you found a better solution. If my answer helped you, consider to accepet and up vote to help the community.